# Designing a maintainable/editable website for a society

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, architecture

first of all apologies for the vague question, I thought I would clarify it in the body.

So basically, I am looking to design a website for my society, as a person with a fair amount of software development know how(or at-least I would like to think so), how can I go about designing a web application that can be edited, from the front end(I know this breaks alot of MVC principles), I want to make it so, that an administrator can login to the administrator account on the web app, and upload/delete a new blog and make aesthetic changes to the application. Is there any way to build/design a web applications this way.

**So basically the program flow would look something like this**

1. Administrators decides to update the blog
2. Administrator logins into the admin account
3. Edits the blog on the website
4. Saves the blog, the edited blog now appears on the front end, visible to all visitors.

Secondly, if the first option is not recommended, what frameworks can I use(preferably python) so that I can ensure the website is as maintainable as possible(after I finish university, I will not be maintaining it ).

Would a common framework such as Django, Flask suffice?

This must all be completed within 4-5 weeks, in a three developer team.

Comment: Also, I do not wish to use sites like WordPress, mainly due to the fact, i wish to connect to some external APIs, down the line

Comment: `django` seems like a good choice for this

Comment: I think what you are looking for is Content Management System (CMS). You can have a look here to see it's possible https://wagtail.io/

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Flask, you can do almost anything you want with it.
When you say "edit blog" you mean "edit posts of the blog" like postbody-text, photos, etc?
These tasks can be done easily with Flask.

You can do the same with Django too, but Django is more heavy and is more suitable for big websites

In practice, you will create some routes in the Flask app with the functionality you want (edit posts, replace photos, etc) that will be accessed by the admin account only